# Projection reduces directional distortion

Tags: coordinate-system, r, polygon, transects

Below R code makes transects within a polygon. When I project the transect to lat long they are distorted, i.e. slanted to the left. Is there a way I can convert the transects to lat long whilst also keeping them straight?

```
install_github("DistanceDevelopment/dssd", build_vignettes = TRUE)

library(tibble); library(sf); library(dssd); library(dplyr); library(sp)

### Make polygon
lon <- c(-2.28693776739262, -2.28775699708943, -2.28703948292762, -2.29244089927134, -2.29166515832837, -2.30186223039892, -2.30309391144779, -2.3056785372324, -2.30317524849752, -2.29377665148526, -2.28749981389358, -2.28693776739262)

lat <- c(55.8178060589878, 55.8176446224019, 55.8143145424301, 55.8134429653489, 55.8125449362038, 55.8111356982306, 55.8143414682509, 55.8151103263674, 55.8178015760052, 55.8220786729108, 55.8200414980507, 55.8178060589878)

df <- tibble(lon, lat)

poly <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

st_transform(poly, crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ") -> poly

### Set up region
region <- make.region(region.name = "study area", shape = poly)

cover <- make.coverage(region, n.grid.points = 1000)

### Design transect
design <- make.design(region = region, design = "systematic", edge.protocol = "minus", design.angle = 0,truncation = 2, coverage.grid = cover, spacing = 100)

### Plot untransformed transects
transects <- generate.transects(design)
```

[image]

```
sp::plot(transects)

### Plot untransformed transects
transects@samplers -> transects

st_transform(transects, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84") -> transects

plot(transects$geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating them using a coordinate system where all latitude lines are parallel and grid-aligned, eg lat-long (4326) or some Mercator projection (3857). You might have to compute the spacing carefully to account for the Mercator distance distortion though...

Comment: Lambert Azmuthal Equal Area meridians converge at the pole.